# I want to move from Identi.ca to Twitter. Is there a way to map identities between the two?

Tags: twitter, identi.ca

I've been using Identi.ca but too many of my contacts won't use it and I want to move to Twitter instead.  Is there a way to go through my list of subscriptions/subscribers and match those to tweeters, so I can do a bulk follow?

Comment: How would this be possible?  How would you be able to link the subscribers on Identi to tweeters?

Answer (score 1):

As Wil has alluded to, that would require that your Identi.ca followers use the same handle as they do on Twitter. While this is likely, it is but by no means a certainty and thus unreliable.

The problem you present suggests that you don't follow that many people on Identi.ca. I would suggest enabling cross-posting from Identi.ca to Twitter, posting to Identi.ca that you're moving, and soliciting @-mentions on Twitter from those people so you can quickly find and follow them.

I don't know of a better solution at this time, I'm afraid.